# Export runnable jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

Need to export clickable and executable file in eclipse. Simple exporting does not launch the program. How to get a clickable jar?

Comment: what exactly did u try search in google ??

Comment: there are two types of jar 1) normal jar of libraries **jar** 2) another is **executable jar**

Comment: You should probably read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

Comment: Srinath, "How to create runnable file from eclipse." Could you create and show me your result ?

Comment: Try this: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should click `file`, then click `export`, then click `java` and save it as `runnable jar file`.

To run the `.jar` file, open cmd or terminal, make sure you are in the right path and

type `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Note if you cant run it, mostly its your file path not correct

[image]

Comment: I have mentioned that i did, but could not run it

Comment: i got your answer, but is there any way to run it without cmd ?

Comment: @FarhadMammadli  Double click on it

Comment: You have to add an entry name `Main-Class` in MANIFEST file, or run as `java -cp <jarfile> <package.mainClass>`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to go in brief using the below link : 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse

Comment: Just visited this site. Still no results:/

Comment: If it is just opening in WINRAR .try to run using javaw <JAR FILE NAME>

Comment: try to run using java -jar <jar file name> and tell is it throwing any exception???

Comment: it runs, but how to do it without cmd ?

Comment: @FarhadMammadli What do you mean, run it without cmd? Its a command line application that expects input from the command prompt itself. The question would make sense if it were for example a Swing or JavaFX application which actually opens up a graphical window.

Comment: @gimby i am beginner in java, thanks for reply, i have to switch to the swing

Comment: @FarhadMammadli okay I understand, I converted that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code listing represents a command prompt application; you can only make it do anything when physically run on the command prompt / shell itself, especially because it expects user input that way. The reason why turning the given program into an executable jar will result in "nothing" happening when you double click it, is because under Windows the default binding for the 'jar' filetype will be setup to run through javaw.exe - and javaw.exe is designed to not open up any command prompt.

In order to make a program be able to run without the command prompt so you only have to double click on it, you will need to get rid of the command prompt interface and instead build a proper graphical user interface, using for example JavaFX or Swing.